# new Audio() in firefox doesn't play

Tags: javascript, audio

The following code to play an mp3 works in Chrome, but not in Firefox:

```
var _audio = new Audio();
_audio.src='http://yinyueshiting.baidu.com/data2/music/121199538/391713118800128.mp3?xcode=6ae40144acd172c6bc707c7a06af5b21a8d402b78e6728f9';
_audio.play();
```

Before, I used the `<audio>` element, but in android chrome, `<audio>`
wouldn't work to switch to the next song, so I tried using `new Audio()` to solve that problem, which apparently created a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var _audio = document.createElement('audio');
_audio.src = 'http://yinyueshiting.baidu.com/data2/music/121199538/391713118800128.mp3?xcode=6ae40144acd172c6bc707c7a06af5b21a8d402b78e6728f9';
_audio.play();
```

Comment: thanks; but if in android chrome; using `document.createElement('audio')` will not switch to the next song